# Erro ao fazer um select com data inicial e final

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Preciso buscar no banco de dados uma lista onde é necessário filtrar pelo funcionário, a data inicial e a data final. 
Porém, quando passa nos parâmetros e entra no while, pula para o catch

```
public List<Nota> BuscarNotas(int funcionarioid, DateTime dataemissaoi, DateTime dataemissaof)
    {
        List<Nota> oNotas = new List<Nota>();
        using (MySqlConnection conexao = ConexaoBD.getInstancia().getConexao())
        {
            try
            {
                conexao.Open();
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
                comando = conexao.CreateCommand();
                comando.CommandText = @"select * from nota where DataEmissao
                                        between DataEmissaoI = @dataemissaoi
                                        and DataEmissaoF = @dataemissaof 
                                        and FuncionarioID  = @FuncionarioID;";
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("FuncionarioID", funcionarioid).ToString();
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("DataEmissaoI", dataemissaoi).ToString();
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("DataEmissaoF", dataemissaof).ToString();

                MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Nota oNota = new Nota();
                    oNota.NotaID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NotaID"].ToString());
                    oNota.FuncionarioID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ClienteID"].ToString());
                    oNota.NumeroNota = reader["NumeroNota"].ToString();
                    oNota.DataEmissao = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataEmissao"].ToString());
                    oNota.Status = (Status)Convert.ToInt16(reader["Status"].ToString());
                    if ((reader["DataPagamentoFinal"] != DBNull.Value))
                        oNota.DataPagamentoFinal = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataPagamentoFinal"].ToString());
                    if ((reader["ValorPago"] != DBNull.Value))
                        oNota.ValorPago = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["ValorPago"].ToString());
                    if ((reader["Desconto"] != DBNull.Value))
                        oNota.Desconto = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Desconto"].ToString());

                    oNotas.Add(oNota);
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
        }
        return oNotas;
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: na Exception tem a informação do erro, que é essencial pra saber o que está acontecendo... não faz sentido vc capturar uma Exception e lança-lá de novo em uma new Exception... e a sintaxe sql está errada, em uma nota você tem duas datas de emissão ? incial e final ? a sintaxe deveria ser `where DataEmissao
                                        between @dataemissaoi and @dataemissaof`

Comment: você deveria ter marcado a questão como resolvida, e aberto outra pergunta para um novo problema, e não edita-la... por favor, faça o [Tour] pra entender como a comunidade funciona. Obs: aqueles `.ToString();` em `Parameters.AddWithValue` não fazem o menor sentido...

Answer (score 0):

Estou assumindo que o `datetimepicker` é em uma aplicação windows form.

Você pode utilizar: `data_Final.Value` para obter um objeto do Tipo `DateTime`.

Ou se deseja a data em formato string pode utilizar o exemplo abaixo:

```
string data = data_Final.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Lodi, Muito obrigada. O erro foi solucionado com o data_Final.Value.
Porém, agora estou com problema ao buscar no banco de dados, você poderia me ajudar? Vou editar a pergunta